# How to change FMX ListBoxGroupHeader text at run-time

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Using FMX, XE8.

I'm trying to work out how to change the Text of a TListBoxGroupHeader at run time.

I have a TListBox where I've added (at design time) a TListBoxGroupHeader as first item.

There are a number of extra items in the list box (with controls on each item - I want these added at design time).

At run time I want to change the text of the ListBoxGroupHeader - I can't work out how to do this.

I've tried:

```
 ListBoxGroupHeader1.Text:='new text';    
 ListBox1.ListItems[0].Text:='new text';    
 TListBoxGroupHeader(ListBox1.ListItems[0]).Text:='new text';    
 TListBoxGroupHeader(ListBox1.ListItems[0]).ItemData.Text:='new text';
```

Nothing changes the text.

Or rather, the Text data is changed, but does not change the Group Header in the listbox. That is, if I drop a label on the form and do: 
lbl1.Text:=lst1.ListItems[0].Text;
then lbl1 displays 'new text'.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

TIA.

EdB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with Delphi XE8 Update 1.

I have the same issue like you. I did following Workaround:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ListBoxGroupHeader1: TListBoxGroupHeader;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBoxGroupHeader1 := TListBoxGroupHeader.Create(ListBox1);
  ListBoxGroupHeader1.Visible := False;
  ListBoxGroupHeader1.Parent := ListBox1;
  ListBoxGroupHeader1.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBoxGroupHeader1.Text := DateTimeToStr(Now);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks - reported in QC as RSP-11510

Comment: Looks like this issue fixed in trial version of Delphi DX 10 (released yesterday)